# Find and replace with regular expression in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, search, sublimetext2

Could anybody please help me to make a regular expression to search and replace a specific text in Sublime Text 2?

I need to find `#=*` where `*` can be any number from one to three digits and replace it with nothing.

I try the following regex: `\#={1,3}`

Comment: What is *ciphers*? Digits? Can you please provide sample text and expected output, **and** what you have tried.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, from one to three digits.
I try the following regex: \#={1,3}

Comment: You forgot the `\d` (or `[0-9]`, for "digits"): `#=\d{1,3}`. See [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rP8gZ8/1). Does it work as expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanx a lot for helping! Works just perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a text starting with `#=` and followed by 1 to 3 digits, you can use

```
#=[0-9]{1,3}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rP8gZ8/1). Beside `[0-9]`, you can match digits with a `\d` shorthand character class, or a Unicode category `\p{N}`.

Note that `#` is not a special regex metacharacter and needs no escaping.

Comment: Sublime's regex search and replace uses PCRE, and doesn't support `\p{XXX}` constructs. Instead, just use `[:digits:]` in this case.

Comment: Sublime Text uses Boost regex library. It only has PCRE like replacement, so it does not support conditional replacement and since it is  not PCRE it does not support `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs. Both PCRE and Boost support Unicode category classes `\p{X}`.